# Automatic object initializing based on type in spring

Tags: java, spring, constructor, javabeans

I have a list of Class types that I need to iterate over and for every type in that list, Spring needs to automatically find the correct sort of object to initialize.

For example : I have a ClassA and ClassB. When for example there is a type User, a ClassA needs to be initialized with certain parameters (which are defined in the context.xml). When for example there is a type of Message, it should also make an object from type ClassA but with different parameters, which are again defined in the context.xml.

How would I go about doing this? I have looked at the inversion of control feature of spring but cannot seem to find the correct implementation for my specific purpose

One idea was that I make a bean for every kind of possible type such as

```
<bean id="classAconfig" class="ClassA">
    <property name="type" value="User.class"/>
    <property name="fields">
        <list>
            <value>id</value><value>email</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="id" value="1"/><entry key="login" value="1"/><entry key="email" value="1"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Kind regards,

Merlijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. Just had to define some beans in the context xml like described above. But in ClassA I extended InitializingBean and overrided the afterPropertiesSet methode. In that methode I registered the ClassA in my service.

```
public class ClassA extends InitializingBean
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    service.registerClass(this);
}
```

And then in my service :

```
public void registerClass(@Nonnull Class clazz) {
    classes.put(clazz.getType(), clazz);
}
```